# Flask html not rendering

Tags: python, flask

Here is my html snippet:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bucket">placeholder1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my flask snippet:

```
@app.route('/bucket')
def bucketlist():
    try:
        return render_template('bucketlist.html')
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
```

When I click on the bucket href on the page, it would spit out 404 instead of the html file that I have. Href to home works fine. How do I fix it so it renders the html template?

EDIT:
Problem is solved, apparently it started working after I got rid of the try/except block.

Comment: Have you passed the `template_folder=` argument on your call to `Flask` to tell it in what directory to find your templates...?

Comment: @AlexMartelli Yes I did, and I got rid of the try/except block and it started working. Weird..

Comment: FWIW, it is unlikely that the `try`/`except` block was entirely the problem. Especially when first using a new framework, there can easily be multiple, overlapping programs that make figuring out which thing was the root cause of a given problem difficult to understand. For example, if the `TemplateNotFound` exception was not properly imported might have been the underlying problem. In general, do not fear to wrap Flask code in exception handlers.

Comment: You could have tried seeing what exception it threw by doing "except TemplateNotFound, e:" and then print e